# How to parse hex color String to Integer

Tags: java, integer, hex, robolectric

I'm working on some code in Robolectric, namely `IntegerResourceLoader`. The following method is throwing a `RuntimeException` when `rawValue` is something such as **0xFFFF0000**:

```
@Override
public Object convertRawValue( String rawValue ) {
    try {
        return Integer.parseInt( rawValue );
    } catch ( NumberFormatException nfe ) {
        throw new RuntimeException( rawValue + " is not an integer." );
    }
}
```

I tried using [Integer.decode(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#decode%28java.lang.String%29) but that throws a NumberFormatException even though the grammar appears to be correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`decode()` is the right method to call but it fails because 0xFFFF0000 is higher than 0x7fffffff max limit for integer. You may want to consider Long.

Answer (score 2):

> The following method is throwing a `RuntimeException` when `rawValue` is something such as `0xFFFF0000`

This is because `Integer.parseInt` isn't designed to handle the `0x` prefix.

> I tried using Integer.decode(String) but that throws a NumberFormatException even though the grammar appears to be correct.

From `Integer.decode` Javadoc (linked in your question):

> This sequence of characters must represent a positive value or a NumberFormatException will be thrown.

`0xFFFF0000` is a negative number, and so this is likely what's causing the exception to be thrown here.

**Solution:**

If you know that the value given will be in the form `0x[hexdigits]`, then you can use [`Integer.parseInt(String, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String) which takes the radix. For hexadecimal, the radix is 16. Like so:

```
return Integer.parseInt(rawValue.split("[x|X]")[1], 16);
```

This uses the regex `[x|X]` to split the string, which will separate `rawValue` on either the lower-case or upper-case "x" character, then passes it to `parseInt` with a radix of 16 to parse it in hexadecimal.

Comment: If you know it's 0x, you don't need to use split (which compiles a regex every time you convert a color), instead you can use an `O(1)` operation: `parseInt(rawValue.substring(2))`. Java Strings are optimized for `substring` (see `offset` and `count` fields in `java.lang.String`)

Comment: That doesn't work. I tried it. java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "98E91E63" whre 98 is Alpha

Comment: @sud007 My solution requires that the string is "0x98E91E63", otherwise you could just use `Integer.parseInt("98E91E63", 16)` to parse the integer.

Comment: @Brian I tried the same `Integer.parseInt("98E91E63", 16)` doesn't work!

Answer (score 2):

This is how android does it:

```
private int parseColor(String colorString) {
    if (colorString.charAt(0) == '#') {
        // Use a long to avoid rollovers on #ffXXXXXX
        long color = Long.parseLong(colorString.substring(1), 16);
        if (colorString.length() == 7) {
            // Set the alpha value
            color |= 0x00000000ff000000;
        } else if (colorString.length() != 9) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown color");
        }
        return (int)color;
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown color");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can strip off the 0x from the front then you can set the radix of parseInt(). So `Integer.parseInt(myHexValue,16)`

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String, int) for more information