# java convert from string to int

Tags: java, string, parsing, int

I need to parse the value of a label so that it can be stored as an Integer

```
JLabel lblSeatNo;
int seatNo;

seatNo = Integer.parseInt(lblSeatNo.getText());
```

It has worked other times I have used with method, however now I am getting a Number Format Exception and I don't understand why.

If it helps with value of the label can vary, it's general format is something like: "A131" or "B504"

Thankyou.

Comment: How would you convert `A131` to an `int`?

Comment: Well neither A131 or B504 are valid numbers!

Comment: If you want to parse them as hexadecimal numbers, just precise the radix. `Integer.parseInt(lblSeatNo.getText(),16);`, otherwise it will use the default radix which is 10.

Comment: They are valid in base 16

Comment: I was told it has to be an it, unless that was a mistake, is it impossible to make it an int?

Comment: You should parse a substring of the seat number which starts after the first character I.e 'Integer.parseInt(lblSeat,getText().substring(1));'

Comment: @NiallConaghan follow ZouZou idea

Comment: `lblSeatNo` doesn't seem very HEX to me.

Comment: Can tell us if the input is intended to be hex numbers or something else?  I'm not sure why people are posting solutions since OP hasn't clarified what the input should be.

Comment: Its not intended to be Hex, the seat number is to be stored in a Flight Booking class that is to be in a LinkedList

Comment: I am thinking of posting a solution that would remove any non-digits from the text, and then parse what remains.  So A131 would be stored as the integer 131.  @Niall, can you please confirm that this is what you actually require?  It's not quite clear from the question.

Comment: Yes, however i need to recall the seat number from the object, will that mean i will loose the leader letter? Im beginning to think storing the seatNo as an Int is a mistake on my lectures behalf.

Comment: Well, you either want an integer, or you want something more.  Perhaps you should get your requirements straight in your own mind, before you ask the Stack Overflow community to write code that meets those requirements.  I am tempted to downvote EVERY answer on this page, for writing code before the requirements were known; but that seems unkind.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want this as a hex number (that is base 16), you must supply the radix to your [parseInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) call -

```
seatNo = Integer.parseInt(lblSeatNo.getText(), 16);
```

if you want the decimal value (e.g. base 10) and to skip the letter, you could do

```
seatNo = Integer.parseInt(lblSeatNo.getText().substring(1));
```

Comment: Who the heck numbers seats with hexadecimal values?!

Comment: @W.K.S As they say in España; Qué?

Comment: The seat numbers are not meant to be Hex, they are meant to stay as "A103" or whatever, and this data is to be stored in a Flight Booking object stored in a LinkedList, im wondering if storing the seatNo in an int is a mistake on my lectures behalf.

Comment: If the plane has less then 6 columns of seats, you can still use hex. Otherwise, you'll need to store the letter and int together (I suggest a class).

Comment: I have a FlightBooking class consisting of int flightno, int seatNo, String forename and surname etc.., i may have to split the letter and number up?

Comment: You may... I don't know your precise use case, but you can get the character with `lblSeatNo.getText().charAt(0)` and use my code above to do that.

Comment: Thanks, ill try it out, to clarify, its impossible to store "B692" as an int?

Comment: "B692" could be a hexadecimal int.... "Z692" could not. What are your requirements?

Answer (score 1):

Try `int value = Integer.parseInt(hexString, 16);` if you know that the string representation will always be hexadecimal. You might also want to check the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) of the method in question.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you are wanting:
If you want to just parse the numbers (not including a, b, etc) then you have to call substring to remove the letter.
if the letter is meant to be there as a hex number then you can call

Integer.parseInt(hexNo, 16)

Answer (score 0):

follow this link

[How to parse hex color String to Integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12269174/how-to-parse-hex-color-string-to-integer)

eg. Integer.parseInt(myHexValue,16)

Answer (score 0):

From your comments it seems like you want to extract just the number from the Seat label. But since you say that you also need to recreate the seat label then in your object you may also want to add a String for the `row` which will contain the Letter

So you could do something like this (assuming only ever a single letter)

```
 int seatNo = Integer.parseInt(lblSeatNo.getText().substring(1));
 String row = lblSeatNo.getText().subString(0,1);
```

Then to get the label again

```
 String label = row + seatNo;
```